# Como fazer para tirar a Virgula da ultima ocorrencia [PERL]

Tags: regex, perl

Bem tenho um script em perl que formata um json deixando ele nesse formato:

```
{"nome1":"123","nome2":"123","nome3":"123",}
```

porem quero que apenas na ultima ocorrencia fique apenas a chave sem a virgula antes.
assim:

```
{"nome1":"123","nome2":"123","nome3":"123"}
```

Codigo:

```
   open(FILEHANDLE, '<', 'prices.json');
   my $file = <FILEHANDLE>;
   close(FILEHANDLE);
   open(salvar,'>>','730.json');
print salvar "{";

while($file =~ m/"name":"(.*?)","price":(.*?),/ig) {

my $name = $1;

my $price = $2 / 100;


print $name.":".$price."\n";
print salvar '"'.$name.'":"'.$price.'"'.",\n";
 }

print salvar "}";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468999/how-can-i-split-a-perl-string-only-on-the-last-occurrence-of-the-separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use essa regex.

```
(.*?)(,)(})
```

Ela vai capturar tudo até a ultima vírgula que será seguida do fechamento de chaves `}`.

Após isto basta fazer um replace com os grupos de captura 1 e 3.
Para usar o conteúdo capturado por esses grupos basta referencia-los desta forma:

```
$1$3
```

Então o resultado será:

```
{"nome1":"123","nome2":"123","nome3":"123"}
```

[Você pode testar essa regex aqui](https://regex101.com/r/IzUoMB/1)

Answer (score 1):

Sem recurso a regex, pode-se fazer o mesmo trocando a ordem das acções. A virgula é adicionada antes de cada membro a partir da segunda iteração.

```
open(FILEHANDLE, '<', 'prices.json');
my $file = <FILEHANDLE>;
close(FILEHANDLE);
open(salvar,'>>','730.json');

print salvar "{";

my $addComma = 0;
while($file =~ m/"name":"(.*?)","price":(.*?),/ig) {
    my $name = $1;
    my $price = $2 / 100;

    print $name.":".$price."\n";
    print salvar ",\n" if ($addComma);
    print salvar '"'.$name.'":"'.$price.'"';
    $addComma = 1;
}

print salvar "}";
```